# showbase and leading zero for stringstream

Tags: c++, hex, wostringstream

Here is the code:

```
std::wstringstream wss;    

wss.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);

wss.setf(std::ios_base::showbase);
// wss << std::showbase;

// wss.width(2);
wss.fill('0');

wss << std::setw(2) << 7;
// wss << std::noshowbase;
wss.unsetf(std::ios_base::showbase);
wss << std::setw(2) << 0;
wss << std::setw(2) << 20;
wss << std::setw(2) << 6;

auto ret = wss.str();
```

If I set `showbase` for the stream, I always get below output:
`0x7001406`, instead of `0x07001406`

How can I get this zero before 7? I don't want to set the prefix `0x` manually like `wss << "0x"`.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Aconcagua for your clue!

I think we can use **std::ios_base::adjustfield** and **std::ios_base::internal** to do it like this:

```
wss.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
int oldFlag = wss.setf(std::ios_base::internal, std::ios_base::adjustfield);
```

Then

```
wss.setf(std::ios_base::showbase);
wss.fill('0');

wss << std::setw(4) << 7;
wss.unsetf(std::ios_base::showbase);
//  wss.setf(oldFlag);

wss << std::setw(2) << 0;
wss << std::setw(2) << 20;
wss << std::setw(2) << 6;
```

Then I get 0x07001406. Correct me if I cannot do it like this, thanks!

Comment: That's fine as well - even better, as using `showbase` and `adjustfield == internal` selects the default prefix defined in C++ standard (can be integrated into my solution, though), and by using the flags directly, you avoid setting and resetting them all the time as in my converter. Just be aware that you need to cast character types to larger integers to prevent ASCII to be printed instead of numbers (additionally that you need to add prefix length to width, but you noted already...).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is: the prefix is part of the output width! Try `wss << std::setw(4) << 7;` for comparison (you now get `00x7`, which still is unwanted...).

Unfortunately, you cannot use `precision` for integers to get a behaviour equivalent to `printf("%#.2x\n", 7);`, which obviously is what you intend...

My personal variant is having my own converter:

```
template <typename T>
struct Hex
{
    Hex(T value, size_t width) : value(value), width(width) { }
private:
    T value;
    size_t width;

    template <typename Stream>
    friend Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, Hex h)
    {
        auto fill = s.fill();
        auto flags = s.flags();
        s.fill('0');
        s << "0x" << std::noshowbase << std::hex << std::setw(h.width) << h.value;
        s.fill(fill);
        s.flags(flags);
        return s;

    }
};
template <typename T>
auto hex(T t, size_t width = sizeof(T) * 2) { return Hex<T>(t, width); }
```

You now can use it as:

```
wss << hex(7, 2);
```

getting even shorter than having `wss << std::setw(2) << 7;` and coming with nice default appropriate to size of the type...

One minor drawback yet: you need specialisations or overloads for signed and unsigned char, as for these, the character representation (`0x0s`) is output instead of numerical value (`0x73`).

```
auto hex(char t, size_t width = sizeof(char) * 2)
{ return Hex<unsigned int>(t, width); }
auto hex(signed char t, size_t width = sizeof(signed char) * 2)
{ return Hex<signed int>(t, width); }
auto hex(unsigned char t, size_t width = sizeof(unsigned char) * 2)
{ return Hex<unsigned int>(t, width); }
```

You might replace `2` with `CHAR_BIT / 4` in the default, depending on your needs/desires, might cover systems having e. g. `CHAR_BIT == 16` better...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Aconcagua!